# How can I force a xor operation to stay within the visible ascii range?

Tags: bit-manipulation

Say you have a value `k in [32,126]` and another value `p in [32,126]`.  If you compute `p xor k` you might get low values such as 0 not in [32,126].  One trick to stay within [32,127] is to compute `p xor (k and 15)`.  The `and(k, 15)` eliminates the 4 most significant bits of `k` while keeping `k`'s least significant bits intact.

However, 127 is a control character in the ASCII table.  Can you do something elegant that makes this range go from 32 to 126 and not 32 to 127?

Comment: `and(k, 31)` should be fine too (still doesn't solve the problem). Also keep in mind that these AND tricks as a side effect ensure that the shuffling only happens in "blocks", so for example upper-case stays upper-case (or a couple of symbols in the same block)

Comment: @harold, I think I found a solution. Instead of computing `and(k,31)` or `and(k,15)`, we can restrict `k in [48,126]`.  Now if `p in [0,126]`, then `r = (p XOR k) in [0,78]`.  If we now add `r + 48` we end up with a value in `[48,126]`, a visible ascii range.  What do you say?

Comment: I don't think that's true, for example take `k = 0x30, p = 0x41`. But it's close and if such further tricks (I mean operations that aren't xor, to fix the result) are allowed then there are some solutions

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.  I thought that my taking the highest visible ascii value (which is 126) and the lowest in `k`, I'd get the maximum value from the `XOR` operation.  But it's not quite like that.

Comment: This is an ill-defined problem. It's like asking how to make 1+2 not equal 3. You need clarify what your constraints are. Must it be an invertible operation etc.